# Enable/Disable textbox inside pop up window

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, textbox, popup

I am working on a project the requires having a pop-up window with some elements like check boxes that will add info to a report , text boxes that will add info to a report or just get info from the database. To be more specific after clicking a search btn, i have a query that will search for a field "name" and if this field exist the text box in pop up window will be shown filled with the info and will not be able to get modified, in the other hand if "name" wont be found in the DB the text box will be shown empty and the user can add the required info. Below is what i have coded until now but is not working since is showing in both cases my text box empty and enabled so the user can writte.

```
 <telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager1" runat="server" Skin="Web20" Title="Application" >
    <Windows>

        <telerik:RadWindow runat="server" ID="Application" Behaviors="Close" Title="Application form"
            Height="350px" Width="500px" Skin="Web20" Modal="true" CenterIfModal="false" Left="230px" Top="65px" >
            <ContentTemplate>
                <table id="table_radWindowReason" border="0">
                <tr>
                         <td>
                             <asp:Label ID="Name" runat="server" 
                             Text="Applicant Name:"></asp:Label>
                         </td>
                        <td> 
                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txbApplicant" 
                             runat="server" visible="true" BackColor="red">
                            </telerik:RadTextBox>

                        </td>      
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                   </ContentTemplate>
                </telerik:RadWindow>



 dt = clsQuery.getName(Id);

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)    // if no name is found
                {
                    txbApplicant.Enabled= false;

                    txbApplicant.Text = dt.Rows[0]["name"].ToString().ToUpper();
                }
                else
                {
                    txbApplicant.Enabled = true;
                }

                showRadWindow(Application.ClientID);

            }
```

the first part of the code as you can see is the .aspx file since i am working in .net and the second part is the code behind

Comment: I would suggest you add a breakpoint at the getName line and then click Start Debugging. Add dt variable to the quickwatch and then step through the code line by line to see which part of your code is actually running. Also check what values are being stored in dt.

Comment: i have already did that, the code is running fine, the query is fine, if "name " is found the text  box is getting the value as it should, but at the end when the pop up is shown the text box is empty and the user can insert text  when in fact should not look like that

Comment: Did you try putting ReloadOnShow="true" in the RadWindow tag?

Comment: @Vlam i just tried it now that you mentioned but looks still the same

Comment: Try both ReloadOnShow="true" and ShowContentDuringLoad="false"

Comment: @Vlam did not worked either. i was thinking if i am calling in the right way the text box since is inside a pop uo. or maybe this should be done from Java Script. i dont know